# Fatou's Lemma - Example

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $$f_n(x)=I_{[n,\infty)}(x)=\begin{cases} 1, x\geq n\\ 0 , x<n\\
> \end{cases}$$ We can see that for all $n$, $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to
>  [0,\infty]$ is lebesgue
>   measurable, $f_n$ is decreasing as a function of $n$, $f_1\geq
> > f_2\geq...$

1.why $[o,\infty]$ and not $[0,1]$?

> and
>
> $$lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0=f(x)$$
>
> But $$\int _{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dm=0\neq \infty=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int
>  _{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)dm$$

2. $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)dm=\infty$ is due to $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)dm=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _{\mathbb{R}}I_{[n,\infty)}dm=m([n,\infty))=\infty?$
3. In general how do we evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)dm$ for a non negative $f_n$

> And due to Fatou's Lemma:
>
> $$\int _{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dm=0< \infty=\liminf\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)dm$$

4. $\infty=\liminf\int _{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)dm$ because if there is a limit so it is equal to the liminf and limsup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ Look up the difference between codomain and image.

$(2)$ Almost. We have $\int_{\Bbb R}f_n(x) \,dx = \int_n^\infty 1\, dx = +\infty$. Because $\int_{\Bbb R}f_n(x) \,dx = +\infty$ for all $n$, the limit as $n\to\infty$ is also $+\infty$.

$(3)$ Like above, evaluate each $\int_{\Bbb R}f_n(x) \,dx$. This is a (extended) real number, so you're just taking the limit of a sequence of real numbers.

$(4)$ $+\infty$ is the $\liminf$ because each term in the sequence is $+\infty$. Your reasoning also works in the context of extended real numbers.

Comment: 1. What I thought, thanks for the conformation 2 and 3. I am trying to use the definition using simple function integration so it is $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)dm=1\cdot I_{[n,\infty)}=1\cdot \mu([n,\infty))=1\cdot\infty=\infty$?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.